# How to run debug for PHP files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm starting with trying to run a connection PHP file `Conn.php` which I am using to connect to SSMS.

I cannot seem to get debug to work. I have tried various StackOverflow solutions but none seem to resolve the problem.

I have installed both
[PHP Debug extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpDYy.png) and [xdebug extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Qgp.png)

```
{
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",

"window.zoomLevel": 1,

"php.validate.enable": true,

"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/Users/Laura.Doorman/Desktop/PWA CODE/Conn.php",

"php.validate.run": "onType"
}
```

This is my `settings.json`. Which I have tried changing.

I have also tried installing code runner and using `ctrl + alt + n` to run the code but I get the error:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.076 seconds

Comment: Have you installed PHP itself on your machine? Read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug as well for more info.

Comment: Yes PHP is installed

Comment: Ok well, as per the instructions in the first link I gave above, the `php.validate.executablePath` setting is supposed to point to the path of the PHP executable on disk, not to the path of the PHP script you wrote. So the value might look something like `c:/php/php.exe` (adjust as necessary depending where you installed it)

Comment: I am getting the error: "Cannot validate since C:/php/php.exe is not a valid php executable." It is in the correct location and the file type is application.

Comment: hm. That sounds strange. Are you **certain** that's the correct path? And what version of PHP did you install?

Comment: yes absolutely certain of the path, I closed visual studio and opened it again and the executable error is no longer present but when i run debugger, we are back to php : The term 'php' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: ok. That really does imply that either the path is not really valid, or that the file you're referencing is not really an executable. The other thing you can try is adding that folder to your Windows %PATH% environment variable - according to the docs if you do that then you don't need to set the `executablePath` setting in VS Code.